# Select rows with time difference and missing rows with default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the query in mysql to select rows with time stamp difference of x seconds. I have mysql sql file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2OtMFmhjDvkSUNQWHpGckxKVXM/view?usp=sharing)

If you try at your end then you can see that at time stamp `2017-05-31 15:59:49` there is only 1 row of `channel_id` 5. **I want to show row for `channel_id` 8 with default value of 0 and `time_stamp`value of `2017-05-31 15:59:49`.** How can i achieve this ?

Note: I have tried this on sql fiddle but it was giving me some error so i have posted the sql file on google drive.

Comment: Try posting script and queries on rextester.com and share the URL, as google drive is not accessible from some locations, (like my office)

Comment: @Utsav :- This is the [link] http://rextester.com/BJT68575

Comment: and channel id is always `5` and `8`?

Comment: @Utsav : Nopes it depends. User can select other channels too..

Comment: so if there is another row with channel say 9, then you need 1 record for channel 9 for all timestamp?

Comment: Yes... If record for the channel 9 is missing for that particular time stamp then it should show 9 ,  0, time_stamp value

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/IEEY74785)

```
select a.channel_id,a.time_stamp,
case when r.value is null then '0' else r.value end as value
from reading r
right join
(select * from 
    (select distinct channel_id  from reading) c
        cross join
     (select distinct time_stamp from reading) t
) a
on r.channel_id=a.channel_id
and r.time_stamp=a.time_stamp
order by a.time_stamp,a.channel_id;
```

Explanation: We need distinct channel_id and timestamp and need to cross join to derive a table `a` which will have all combination of channel_id and time_stamp. Now Right join main table with this table `a` and hardcode `0` for missing values.

Comment: I am showing records after every 2 seconds.  Well i am trying to get that delay of 2 seconds. Your answers full fills the missing part.

Comment: It was not very clear from the sample. Can you create a small sample with few rows with both cases, and give your expected output.

Comment: In rextester link above if you scroll down and at the bottom i have written select statement that selects rows with time difference of 2 sec.